Troubles with plugins in CKEditor
I have troubles with plugins in CKEditor. I want to use table plugins such as Table, TableCellProperties, TableProperties, TableToolbar, but I have some errors when I adding them in config. So here is my config:
import { EditorConfig } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core";
import {
  Table,
  TableCellProperties,
  TableProperties,
  TableToolbar,
} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table";

export const editorConfig: EditorConfig = {
  language: "en",
  plugins: [
    Table,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar
  ],
  table: {
    contentToolbar: [
      "tableColumn",
      "tableRow",
      "mergeTableCells",
      "tableProperties",
      "tableCellProperties",
    ],
  },
  removePlugins: [...],
  toolbar: {
    removeItems: [...]
  },
};

Here is versions
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^43.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^43.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^43.3.1",

And here is error: 
How can I solve this problem? This error occurs on each of plugins.

What builder are you using?
If you're using Vite, please check this guide:
Integrating CKEditor 5 from source using Vite
And here is for Webpack Integrating CKEditor 5 from source using Webpack
These configurations handle loading the SVG icons, styles from the packages, and the theme package.

I am using webpack, but I dont understant how to use it. I dont have packajes like theme as in docs you show

Here you can find that adding packages requires a theme, default theme for ckeditor 5 is ckeditor5-theme-lark, adding it will help you load SVG icons
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/legacy/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source-vite.html#installing-necessary-dependencies
